# Is it possible that small SD Cards are formatted without an MBR?

Tags: embedded, partitioning, sd-card, mbr

I'm trying to implement a read only FAT16/32 Filesystem library for embedded systems, to read SD Cards (reinventing the wheel for educational purpose).

It seems like there are cards which are formatted without an MBR; just the FAT without any partition table.

I have read FAT docs and MBR docs and learnt how to read an SD Card which both has MBR and FAT.

I need my C++ library to support reading SD Cards without an MBR.

My current approach is the following:

> 1. Try reading the first sector assuming it contains FAT BPB (Boot
>      Parameter Block).
> 2. Check whether the information is valid.
> 3. If yes, continue reading root directory.
> 4. Otherwise assume it has an MBR.
> 5. Read the partition table starting at 0x1BE.
> 6. If a supported partition type is available, try reading its first sector as FAT.
> 7. If the read information is valid, continue reading root directory.
> 8. Otherwise return an ERROR_CODE

Is there a better approach? For example, is there any magic number or a specific pattern that can be identified?

Comment: you just read and see if it is there?

Comment: is there any magic number or specific pattern to identify?

Comment: or is there a way to distinguish between the first sector of FAT and the MBR?

Comment: I thought that was by location, the wikipedia page for master boot record doesnt help here?

Comment: I looked through a lot of introductory docs. But I just couldn't find a key difference.

Comment: of course you cant assume EVERY card will have X any more than every hard drive will have X.  some may be wiped clean or partitioned differently or used without a file system.  All it takes is one on the planet not being that way and the answer to your question is no, you cannot count on that fact.

Comment: So just try to read the first sector. Check if it is a valid FAT boot sector. If not, then try to read the partition table and loop through each partition trying to find a valid FAT boot sector. That's it?

Comment: Just because a FAT FS floppy is not bootable does not mean that it has no MBR - merely that the MBR does not load a boot sector.

Comment: @Clifford, yes. I meant there existed floppies which did not have an MBR.

Comment: @happycoder : Really? Were they FAT?  What I am doubting is that such things existed.

Comment: This maybe relevant: http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/sd-card-missing-mbr

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Check for the text FAT32 at offset 0x52.
> 2. If that fails, check for FAT12 or FAT16 at 0x36
> 3. If that fails too, assume the first sector is MBR.

Thanks to @Clifford